# Undo pull from another branch

Tags: git

I have a branch named "lemon". I wanted to pull changes into it from my peers by doing:

```
git pull --rebase origin lemon
```

but I accidentally ran:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

I killed the process before it went through (mostly) ugh. I'm back to my directory now, and trying to run:

```
git pull --rebase origin lemon
```

gives me the following output:

```
It seems that I cannot create a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of patch application or another
rebase.  If that is not the case, please

  rm -fr /Users/me/project/.git/rebase-apply

and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

so it looks like it was part way through doing the unwanted pull/rebase, and knows something is up. How do I cancel whatever was undone? Is the above message telling me the command I should run to do that (rm -fr ..) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git rebase --abort`

That should take care of the issue by canceling the original rebase